# What does 'ItemsSource="{Binding}"' mean?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm attempting to learn WPF by unravelling a frankly nightmarish project written by the guy who was in this job before me. Sorry if some of my questions are pretty much homework-level but I'm trying to work out what existing XAML does, with an insufficient understanding of the concepts behind it...

Anyway, I have a ListView with this as part of its definition:

```
<ListView 
    DataContext="{StaticResource XMLFileGroups}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource XMLItemStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Now, I can kind of get my head around what the "DataContext" and "ItemContainerStyle" lines are doing; they appear to be referencing a method of sorting an existing list, and a structure defining some visual behaviour of the ListView, respectively.

What's wrecking me is the fact that the ItemsSource is listed as "{Binding}". All that says to me is that there is some kind of databinding in place, but I don't understand how the line can possibly be meaningful and yet removing it stops any data from being displayed.

Can someone shed some light on what is happening here, or where I should look for the actual binding definition? I just don't understand what I'm seeing, here.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Without a path, `{Binding}` will bind to the `DataContext` itself.
Adding a path will bind to a property of the datacontext.

Comment: So "{Binding}" specifically links back to the collection being created by the DataContext property of the ListView? Is this something that generally happens for View-type objects or is it specific to ListView? Apologies for begging for more information, but I'm sure you can appreciate that searching for 'ItemsSource="{Binding}"' isn't a narrow enough search for me to be getting many results, hence my asking this question in the first place...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `{Binding}` can be used in any context where the value you want to bind to is the `DataContext` itself.  It's most frequently used to bind a DataSource.

Comment: I thought that was the case, but I couldn't really be sure. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 8):

That example specifies that the binding **is** the DataContext. The same thing in the code behind would be

```
MyList.ItemsSource = new Binding();
```

You can also do stuff like:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding YourBindingField, Source={StaticResource YourStaticDataSource}}"
```

which would translate to this in code behind:

```
        MyList.ItemsSource = new Binding() {ElementName = "YourBindingField", Source = YourStaticDataSource};
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that what I'm working on is (in theory) an MVVM project, so there isn't any code-behind. While I'm sure what you say is correct, I don't have any context in which to interpret it.