# Create bindings of ListView items programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following wpf control added to xaml:

```xml
<ListView Margin="22,80,271,12" Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  />
```

I know how to create a ListView object programmatically. The only thing that I am missing is how could I add the property

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

with code to that object. I have already managed to add the columns and gridview with c#. The only thing that I am missing is to add that property ItemsSource="{Binding}"

I have tried looking for an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874218/what-does-itemssource-binding-mean/3874319#3874319).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortest should be this (literal translation of XAML):

```
listView1.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listView1.ItemsSource = listView1.DataContext as IEnumerable;
```

Comment: `ItemsSource` is a property on the `ListView`, which inherits from `ItemsControl`, which is in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace. add a using statement for `System.Windows.Controls`

Comment: It does not bind I don't know why?  I also tried:  listView.ItemsSource = listView.DataContext as IEnumerable<DynamicListViewItem>;  Because the listview is populated with DynamicListViewItem Objects

Comment: Technically this is not the same as creating a binding between ItemsSource and DataContext. You are simply setting them to the same object. If DataContext changes the ItemsSource will still point to the old value. Please see my answer for how you do the binding.

Comment: I had to add the objects to the listView then Bind it using: : listView.ItemsSource = listView.DataContext as IEnumerable<DynamicListViewItem>; Thanks!

Comment: This gives me problems when I try to filter the results.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.ElementName = "item-you-are-binding-to";
myBinding.Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("property-you-are-binding-to");
listView1.SetBinding(ContentProperty, myBinding);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is this:

```
var binding = new Binding("DataContext");
binding.Source = listView1;
listView1.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```