# ItemsSource="{Binding}" without an apparent DataContext

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm learning WPF and currently studying [this MSDN resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).  At the moment, I'm focusing on a particular line in a data template from the supplied downloadable code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
<TabControl 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
    Margin="4"
    />
</DataTemplate>
```

I understand, e.g. from resources such as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874218/what-does-itemssource-binding-mean), that `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` will bind to the associated `DataContext`, but whereas the example in the latter SO post shows a `DataContext`:

```
<ListView 
DataContext="{StaticResource XMLFileGroups}"
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource XMLItemStyle}"
ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

I cannot find one in my example above.  Can someone please help me see what I'm missing here?

**>>UPDATE:**

Based on comments, I understand now that the data context comes from the container that uses the `DataTemplate`, so here is the XAML from `MainWindow` where the template it being used.  Note that I still can't find a `DataContext` anywhere:

```
<Window 
  x:Class="DemoApp.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DemoApp.ViewModel"
  FontSize="13" 
  FontFamily="Verdana"
  MinWidth="650" MinHeight="420"
  Title="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
  Width="650" Height="420"
  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
  >
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None">
      <Menu KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
          <MenuItem Header="E_xit" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Options" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
      </Menu>
    </DockPanel>

    <Grid Margin="4">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Border 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}"
        Width="170"
        >
        <HeaderedContentControl
          Content="{Binding Path=Commands}"
          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommandsTemplate}"
          Header="Control Panel"
          Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"
          />
      </Border>

      <Border
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}"
        >
        <HeaderedContentControl 
          Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
          Header="Workspaces"
          Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"
          />
      </Border>
    </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

FYI, the `WorkspacesTemplate` is being used 8 lines from the bottom in case you can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The data context in first case is context provided by parent control to which this Template is applied.

So wherever you use this data template, that control will set the context.

Comment: Please see the updates to my question.  I've included the XAML that uses the template but cannot locate a data context.

Comment: in your case, its the data context of the window

Comment: Specifically, where is that defined?  I literally can't find the term "DataContext" in the XAML for the window.

Comment: well if you are not using any framework, most likely place is code behind

Comment: It is not necessary to keep DataContext in XAML, some time you can find the DataContext defined in the code behind.